# Does an immediate interrupt trap stop an action?

Tags: dnd-4e

My question is simply this: does a trap with an immediate interrupt property stop an action?

If I was moving and triggered a trap that fires a crossbow at me, does it interrupt my movement? Does it matter if it's a hit or a miss?

I would think that it never stops my movement hit or miss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am grabbing this reference from the PHB1 (page 268):

> Interrupt: An immediate interrupt lets you jump in when a certain trigger condition arises, acting before the trigger resolves. If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, that action is lost. For example, an enemy makes a melee attack against you, but you use a power that lets you shift away as an immediate interrupt. If your enemy can no longer reach you, the enemy’s attack action is lost.

From the above I would surmise that if the trap's effect said that the target is slowed or immobilized (on a hit) than it would stop the movement, else you'd take the damage and then continue on as damage alone wouldn't negate the rest of your movement.